# Error while configuring Hadoop in stand alone operation

Tags: hadoop, cygwin

When I am giving this command:

```
 bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

I am getting these errors:

```
: No such file or directoryn/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 26: 
cd: /cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec

/cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 80: 
syntax error: unexpected end of file

cygpath: can't convert empty path
bin/hadoop: line 350: /cygdrive/C:/Program: No such file or directory

cygpath: can't convert empty path
bin/hadoop: line 434: /cygdrive/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/java: 
No such file or directory

bin/hadoop: line 434: exec: /cygdrive/C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

I am not getting why am I getting these errors.